# Graphs given a set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am given the following graph: the set of vertices is $V(G) = \{1 \dots 2n \}$ such that the set of vertices $S = \{1 \dots n\}$ has the maximum possible amount of edges. I am asked to find how many possible graphs are there with these conditions, and I wanted to see if my approach was right:

From above one easily deduces that the vertices of S form a $K_n$, which is the complete graph of $n$ vertices. Now, the problem comes when finding the possible connections between the vertices of $S$ and $T = \{n+1 \dots 2n\}$. For the edges included in the set of vertices $T$, there are $2^{{n \choose 2}}$ possible graphs. Now, the remaining part would be the connections between $T$ and $S$. For each vertex in T, there are $n$ possible edges with a vertex of $S$, therefore there are $n^n$ possible edges and one has to decide whether the edge is in the graph or not (that is why there is a two powered to ${n \choose 2}$), then the answer is $2^{n^n + {n \choose 2}}$.

This is my reasoning, but the number seems a bit weird and maybe too big. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not $n^n$ possible edges between $S$ and $T,$ but $n^2,$ since you have $n$ choices for a vertex from $S,$ combined with $n$ choices for a vertex from $T.$ So the answer is
$$
2^{n^2+\binom{n}{2}}
$$

Here is another way to look at this: in total you have $\binom{2n}{2}$ edges, and you can choose from any of them except for $\binom{n}{2}.$ So you can choose from $\binom{2n}{2}-\binom{n}{2}$ edges. But
$$
\binom{2n}{2}-\binom{n}{2} = n^2+\binom{n}{2},
$$
so same answer both ways.

Comment: Why? Aren' there $n$ posible choices for $n$ vértices?

Comment: Yes, so $n$ choices for $S$ and $n$ choices for $T$ gives $n\cdot n=n^2$ choices.

Comment: It seems right what you said, thanks